# EOutOfMemory when open TFDQuery for one record

Tags: sql-server, delphi, firedac

1. When I try to get one record from a table I get an error. I use `TFDQuery (select SLDDATA, SLDTIME  from TSYSLOGDATA WHERE SLDTIME = '2019-12-11 00:00:00.000')`

   exception class    : EOutOfMemory
   main thread ($6a28):
   00bfaeda +066 TDAdmin.exe  FireDAC.Phys.ODBCWrapper  3752  +13 TODBCVariable.AllocLongData
   00bff3f8 +1a8 TDAdmin.exe  FireDAC.Phys.ODBCWrapper  5178  +51 TODBCStatementBase.GetLongVar
   00bff52b +06b TDAdmin.exe  FireDAC.Phys.ODBCWrapper  5225  +10 TODBCStatementBase.FetchLateBindedColumns
   00bff63b +0ff TDAdmin.exe  FireDAC.Phys.ODBCWrapper  5266  +29 TODBCStatementBase.Fetch
   00c09ffa +05a TDAdmin.exe  FireDAC.Phys.ODBCBase     2996   +7 TFDPhysODBCCommand.InternalFetchRowSet
   00be8742 +066 TDAdmin.exe  FireDAC.Phys              8669   +8 DoFetch

Database is on MS SQL Server. The table has two columns SldDate DateTime and SldData Nvarchar(max). No primary key. SldData contains 422971068 bytes string. As I investigated this long string is a reason of the issue.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

2. I got the same error for 211485518 bytes string.
3. I got an access violation when I tried to used a parameter

   FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT :SYSLOGDATA = SLDDATA FROM TSYSLOGDATA WHERE SLDTIME = ''2019-12-15 00:00:00.000''';
   with FDQuery1.Params[0] do begin
     DataType := ftWideMemo;
     ParamType := ptOutput;
   end;
   FDQuery1.Command.CommandKind := skExecute;
   FDQuery1.ExecSQL;

Project Project1.exe raised exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x004075bf: write of address 0x6b3b0000'.

```
System.Move(???,???,???)
:004075bf Move + $77
FireDAC.Phys.ODBCBase.ProcessArrayItem(???,???,0,???)
FireDAC.Phys.ODBCBase.TFDPhysODBCCommand.GetParamValues(???,0,-1)
FireDAC.Phys.ODBCBase.TFDPhysODBCCommand.InternalExecute(1,0,???)
FireDAC.Phys.Process_HandleSystemFailure(1,0,-1,False)
FireDAC.Phys.Process_SingleRow
FireDAC.Phys.TFDPhysCommand.ExecuteBase(1,0)
FireDAC.Phys.TFDPhysCommandAsyncExecute.Execute
FireDAC.Stan.Async.TFDStanAsyncExecutor.ExecuteOperation(False)
FireDAC.Stan.Async.TFDStanAsyncExecutor.Run FireDAC.Phys.TFDPhysCommand.ExecuteTask(TFDPhysCommandAsyncExecute($2A8BDF8) as IFDStanAsyncOperation,TFDCommand($29904D0) as IFDStanAsyncHandler,False)
FireDAC.Phys.TFDPhysCommand.Execute(???,???,False)
FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomCommand.InternalExecute(0,0,False)
FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomCommand.Execute(0,0,False)
FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDAdaptedDataSet.DoExecuteSource(0,0)
FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.Execute(0,0)
FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomQuery.ExecSQL
```

4. I tried to get data by chunks like this. I run first sql script. Got data and put to local variable. And I got the same error EOutOfMemory on the second sql script when I tried to get data from the field (FDQuery1.Fields[1].AsString)

SELECT SUBSTRING(SLDDATA, 1, 100000000) SLDDATA, SLDTIME FROM TSYSLOGDATA 
SELECT SUBSTRING(SLDDATA, 100000001, 200000000) SLDDATA, SLDTIME FROM TSYSLOGDATA

Comment: A 422MB chunk of data is going to cause problems in 32 bit software if you try and process it all at once. Need to chose between breaking it up / steaming it or using 64 bit software.

Comment: Perhaps there are several buffers involved each holding their copy of this data. Even if there is enough free memory, it may be not available in one block.

Comment: @Brian 422**MB** is no problem for 32bit software. 422**GB** is.

Comment: @UweRaabe it would take several copies of a 422**MB** buffer to eat up available memory, though

Comment: @RemyLebeau, given that in 32-bit we usually have 2GB available memory, that would be about 5 copies of that buffer to fill - assuming the program doesn't use any other memory and the fragmentation allows to allocate each as one block.

Comment: @RemyLebeau:  Not arguing , just interested.  Isn't a 422Mb row going to require at least two contiguous blocks of that size, one in the MDac layer to re-assemble the field from SqlServer's TDS and one for the Delphi app's field buffer?

Comment: Thank you for comments guys, I have played with data and I got the same error when I had 211485518 bytes in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use Blob Streaming:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Support_for_Blob_Streaming_in_FireDAC
Quote from above:

> The client side memory usage is minimized, comparing to the "by value"
>   requirement for additional memory usage equal to 3-4 time of the BLOB
>   value size;

Comment: Do you mean I have to use SQL Server FILESTREAM together with a stream? I could not find how I can load data from field to stream. I tried this but it does not work.
  FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT :Res = SlDData FROM TSYSLOGDATA WHERE SLDTIME = ''2019-12-15 00:00:00.000'' ';
  FDQuery1.Params[0].DataType := ftStream;
  FDQuery1.Params[0].ParamType := ptOutput;
  FDQuery1.Params[0].StreamMode := smOpenReadWrite;
  FDQuery1.OpenOrExecute;
  FDQuery1.Params[0].AsStream.Read(Buffer, Length(Buffer));